# Search my onedrive returns invalidRequest in ms graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

This is the example query from graph explorer:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='finance')?select=name,id,webUrl`

Currently https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search seems to fail both in my own tenant as well as in microsofts test tenant. I am under the impression that the demo queries are supposed to always work in the test tenant (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer - do not log in, use sample data). This leads me to believe that there is a general problem with this function in ms graph at the moment.

Anyone else experiencing the same problem?
Should I use a different method for searching onedrive?

Comment: We're seeing this problem, too. It seems to be user-specific...some users get a 200 response, others get this 400 invalidRequest response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original query worked fine until last friday, it still seems to be broken.

But a viable workaround is using :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userId>/drive/root/search(q='finance')?select=name,id,webUrl
```

Seems to be working without any need to change api permissions on the app, so that'll be fine for now.